# Route separation in express routing with passing passport instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, passport.js

I'm trying to add user-login module to an existing app in node. It is using separate route files for each module and one main route file to use all the child routes which is ultimately used in server.js
When I try to pass passport instance to the user route, it gives me error as passport is not defined. Here is my app code and structure:

```
app
    views
        user
            index.ejs
            login.ejs
            signup.ejs
            profile.ejs
    routes
        docs
            index.js
        user
            index.js
        index.js
    config
        passport.js

    server.js
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const path = require('path')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
    const passport = require('passport')
    const flash = require('connect-flash')
    const session = require('express-session')

    const routes = require('./routes/')

    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    require('./config/passport')(passport);

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


    app.use(session({ secret: '********' })); 
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());

    app.use('/', routes)(app,passport);

    const server = app.listen(port, function(){
      console.log('Server listening on port '+port);
    });
```

config/passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const sql = require('mssql')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')

module.exports = function(passport) {


    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (username, done) {
        done(null,username);
    });


    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {


        var strSQL = "SELECT count(id) as uCount FROM <tbl> WHERE username = '"+email+"'";
        var cb1 = function(err,recordset){
            if(recordset[0].uCount>0){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else{
                var strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO <tbl>(username, password) VALUES('"+email+"','"+generateHash(password)+"')";
                var cb2 = function(err,recordset){
                    return done(null, recordset,req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email registered successfully.'));
                };
                executeQuery(strSQL1,'INSERTION','<tbl>',cb2);
            }
        };
        executeSelection(strSQL,'SELECTION','<tbl>',cb1);
        });

    }));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { 

        var strSQL = "SELECT a.count, id, username, password FROM <tbl> c , (SELECT COUNT(dbid) count FROM <tbl> b WHERE b.username = '"+email+"' ) a WHERE c.username = '"+email+"'";
        var cb1 = function(err,recordset){
            if(recordset[0].uCount <= 0){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
            } 

            if (!validPassword(password,recordset[0].password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 

            return done(null, recordset[0]);
        };
        executeSelection(strSQL,'SELECTION','<tbl>',cb1);

    }));

};

executeSelection = function(strSQL, operationType, tableName, cb){
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);

    request.query(strSQL,function(err,recordset) {
        if(err){
            logger.error('ERROR in '+operationType+' ON '+tableName+': '+err);
        }
        logger.info(operationType+' ON '+tableName+' successful!');
        cb(err,recordset);
    });

};

executeQuery = function(strSQL, operationType, tableName, cb,validateClient) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(strSQL,function(err, recordset) {
        if(err){
            logger.error('ERROR in '+operationType+' ON '+tableName+': '+err);
        }
        logger.info(operationType+' ON '+tableName+' successful!');
        if(cb){
            cb(validateClient);
        }
    });
};

generatePasswordHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

validatePassword = function(curPass, dbPass) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(curPass, dbPass);
};
```

routes/index.js

```
const mainroute = require('express').Router()

    /* ---- other existing routes included ---- */
    const r_docs = require('./docs')
    const r_user = require('./user')    /*my custom route*/

    /* ---- all other routes ---- */
    mainroute.use('/docs', r_docs);
    mainroute.use('/user', r_user)(app, passport);      /*my custom route*/

    mainroute.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.render('home');
    });

    module.exports = function(app, passport){
        mainroute;
    }
```

routes/user/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('user/index.ejs');
    });

    router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('user/login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
    });

    // process the login form
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
        failureFlash : true
    }));

    router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
        res.render('user/signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
    });

    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', 
        failureRedirect : '/signup',
        failureFlash : true 
    }));

    router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('user/profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user 
        });
    });

    router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.redirect('/');
    }

    module.exports = function(app, passport) {
      router;
    }
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap your `main` and `user` routes to run their logic when you call them and at end return prepared route:

*routes/index.js*

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  const mainroute = require('express').Router()

  /* ---- other existing routes included ---- */
  const r_docs = require('./docs');
  const r_user = require('./user'); /*my custom route*/

  /* ---- all other routes ---- */
  mainroute.use('/docs', r_docs);
  mainroute.use('/user', r_user)(app, passport); /*my custom route*/

  mainroute.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
  });

  return mainroute;
};
```

*routes/user/index.js*

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/index.ejs');
  });

  router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/login.ejs', {
      message: req.flash('loginMessage')
    });
  });

  // process the login form
  router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
  }));

  router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/signup.ejs', {
      message: req.flash('signupMessage')
    });
  });

  router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
  }));

  router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('user/profile.ejs', {
      user: req.user
    });
  });

  router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });

  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();

    res.redirect('/');
  }

  return router;
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason why module.exports = function(app,passport){return router;}  won't work but enclosing whole block in module.exports would??
Still new to node, thus looking for some explanation.

Comment: Because your router needs *app* and *passport* parameters for routing. when you just `module.exports = function(app, passport) { return router; }` *app* and *passport* are out of scope and so `undefined`

Comment: and we can't pass them such that both vars are in scope for export block?
Just in case one needs to follow a consistent export method throughout the application.

Comment: No, atleast not this way. `exports` is just a regular object. It only exports everything you attach to it. It does not have any sence of its surrounding module env. What we are doing here is a well known pattern used in relation to writing modules called **dependency injection**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to require it at the top of your user/index.js.  Simply:

```
var passport = require('passport');
```

Then to make sure the user is authenticated:

```
router.get('/some/path', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var user          = req.user;
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```